# MATLAB: LSQNONLIN changes in R2011a?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, matlab

I'm working with a matlab code package that was handed down to me. It was written in `R2007b` version, and I saw it perform. My lab just acquired `R2011a` and although the package runs without errors, it produces different (and notably worse) results.

I've zeroed in on the conclusion that the difference comes when executing [lsqnonlin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html)

Were there any known and significant changes in the versions? How would I track down the differences?
I'll be glad to supply parts of code if needed.

Thank you!

Comment: You can dig through the Matlab release notes here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/rn/rn_intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2008, Matlab changed a few of the default parameters for the optimization toolbox, so you need to figure out what exactly u need to change back

look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/rn/bre20mn.html#brg9c_b) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/rn/bro3heq-1.html#bro3hf_)

Comment: I've added 4 `optimset` settings, and although it didn't resolve the problem completely - this is the answer I was looking for. Thanks!