# MATLAB: lsqnonlin code from 2010b not working in 2008a

Tags: mathematical-optimization, matlab

I've written a script in MATLAB 2010 in which I called the lqnonlin function and it worked fine.

```
options = optimset('TolFun',0.001,...
                   'Display','off',...
                   'Algorithm','levenberg-marquardt');
[X,R2,r] = lsqnonlin(@FCN,XO,[],[],options);
```

I then ran the code in MATLAB 2008a as follows (after reading [MATLAB: LSQNONLIN changes in R2011a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194790/matlab-lsqnonlin-changes-in-r2011a))

```
options = optimset('TolFun',0.01,...
                   'Display','off',...
                   'LargeScale','off',...
                   'LevenbergMarquardt','on')
[X,R2,r] = lsqnonlin(@FCN,XO,[],[],options);
```

It's giving an output, but not giving the correct answer - in fact it remains unchanged from the original inputs

Thinking/hoping it's to do with my options settings

### Solved

Had to tweak 'TolFun' to a far lower setting. no idea why.

Comment: maybe you should post your solution as answer, and mark the question as solved

Answer (score 1):

Was a 'TolFun' issue. Had to set it far lower (1e-9). Though I have no idea why this is. The rest of the code is identical.